# How to use node modules from command line?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I can't find any straightforward instructions on this. I've installed node.js and npm, then created a project in its own folder, `D:\node_stuff`, then cd'd there via `cmd` (Windows 10) and ran `npm install express`, `npm init`. I'm trying to use [gifify](https://github.com/vvo/gifify), and installed its dependencies via `npm` instead of `brew` (ffmpeg, imagemagick, giflossy).

- `gifify -h` -> 'gifify' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
- `node gifify -h` -> Error: Cannot find module 'D:\node_stuff\gifify'
- `cd node_modules` -> `node gifify -h` -> nothing happens

What am I doing wrong? Where do I even look - all tutorials with simple search only show how to install packages or build a project - I don't need to build anything, only to use this one module.

Comment: On Mac/Linux, because you installed the package locally rather than globally, you would typically use `npx` to run it e.g. `npx gifify -h`. Not sure this is available on Windows but please try.

Comment: @jarmod Nice, it worked - I'll see if the rest of functionality works, then you can post it as an answer. Strange how multiple articles didn't mention it.

Comment: to add it to path would need to do `npm i gifify -g`, its in the [readme](https://github.com/vvo/gifify#installation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run `npx gifify -h`.

Generally, you have two options when installing NPM packages:

1. install globally e.g. `npm install gifify -g`
2. install locally e.g. `npm install gifify` (or `npm install` if the package is listed in package.json)

Some packages, when installed, also install a command-line script. For globally-installed packages, that CLI script is installed to a location that is in your PATH and hence you can simply run the bare command e.g. `gifify -h`. For locally-installed packages, that CLI script is installed locally under the `node_modules` folder, which is not in your PATH. To run such a script you can use the NPM package executor [npx](https://github.com/npm/npx), for example `npx gifify -h`. This essentially executes the local script from the `node_modules/.bin` folder.

If your package script, e.g. `gifify`, relies on third-party executables such as FFMPEG and ImageMagick, then I would install those as regular applications (which will put them on your PATH).

Comment: Ran into other troubles, but likely so will other users: some packages fail to be "found" by node by the module used. For example, `npx gifify clip.mp4 -o clip.gif` -. "Could not find ffmpeg. Is it installed?" Yes, via `npm install ffmpeg`, both locally and globally (`-g`). Solution was `choco install ffmpeg`. Now another problem: "Could not find convert. Is it installed?" `choco` didn't work this time, nor did `npm`; any other 'tricks'?

Comment: I'd assume that gifify is execing ffmpeg/convert and because they are not on your PATH it fails to exec them. The gifify package, and others, don't emulate the behavior of npx. You could simply supplement your PATH environment variable with "node_modules\.bin" and then execute `gifify -h` or `npx gifiy -h` (assuming that ffmpeg is in node_modules\.bin). For me personally, I'd probably install FFMPEG and ImageMagick globally as standalone executables rather than through NPM and they'd be added to my PATH. Also, watch out that there is a native Windows convert program which is an NTFS utility.

Comment: `gifify` now runs after restarting cmd, but `node_modules/convert` still not found; is there a "run with debug info" flag? "Not found" isn't telling me much

Comment: Believe that convert is part of ImageMagick.

Comment: Yeah, installing ImageMagick from [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) worked, and finally I get to an error that's from the program itself - but not topic of this Q&A. Thanks for the help.